# Action Center and Performance Information messed up

Tags: control-panel

Does anyone have any idea why these might have happened? I suddenly realized that these had happened after months of use.

Action center is disabled and control panel item doesn't do anything on click:
[image]

Performance information doesn't run on click (even when I plug in the laptop), and the data is messed up: (It works fine on the command-line, though)
[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but just to be on the safe side, I would do a diskcheck on the HDD and then do an "sfc /scannow" at the command line. This will chech the HDD for consistency and sfc will check the systems integrity for critical system files

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I haven't had any viruses or bad sectors or a corrupted file system, and this is a prolonged issue... it's not getting fixed with those. :\

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Windows: %LastChecked% is obviously a placeholder for the value, so some code isn't executing correctly. I just can't figure out what's causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, installing Service Pack 1 fixed the problem.